# RxJava group by timestamp

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java

I have a problem to solve and RxJava seems to be a proper way to handle this kind of thing, but Im kinda lost with all this variety of different operators and not sure which one will work in my case.

I have a finite stream of objects of following type:

```
class MyObject {
    long timestamp;
    Object data;
}
```

My goal - is to group them by timestamp. Lets say every new hour new group needs to be generated, so I have a collection of groups which represent events for each hour.

I looked at `groupBy` operator, but Im not sure I fully understand key selector and element selector concepts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a straightforward job to `groupBy`. The key-selector lets you chose the keys by which the groups will be established. Think of it like the SQL statement with `GROUP BY`. The value selector let's you extract what you'd want to observe in each group which doesn't need to be the whole object but just parts of it; this is equivalent to an SQL `SELECT`.

With your case, this is how it can be done:

```
source
.groupBy(
    v -> v.timestamp / 3_600_000L , 
    v -> v.data
);
```

This will give you a sequence of `GroupedObservable<Long, Object>`. The hour calculation is rudimentary and depending on your environment, you could use something like jodatime or Java 8's new date API to perform accurate calculations.

Comment: Thanks a lot! For some reason grouping selector appeared more complex to me :( Anyway, when you have some time - could you please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32570118/rxjava-debounce-by-arbitrary-value ? Thanks!