# RxJava debounce by arbitrary value

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java

Still figuring out a proper use of different Rx* operators and stumbled upon the following problem:

I have a collection of models of the following type:

```
class Model {

    final long timestamp;
    final Object data;

    public Model(long timestamp, Object data) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

This collection is sorted in ascending order (sorted by timestamp).

My goal - is to group them by "sequences". "Sequence" - is sequence of elements where each element is really close to its neighbor:

```
----A-B-C-----D-E-F---H-I--->
```

In this case I have 3 "sequences". Position on the axis is defined by Model's `timestamp` property (not the emission time). Max distance to form a sequence should be configurable.

Or let's take more real example:

```
List<Model> models = new ArrayList<Model>(10) {{
    add(new Model(0, null));
    add(new Model(5, null));
    add(new Model(10, null));
    add(new Model(100, null));
    add(new Model(108, null));
    add(new Model(111, null));
    add(new Model(115, null));
    add(new Model(200, null));
    add(new Model(201, null));
    add(new Model(202, null));
}};
```

In this case for max distance 10ms, I would get 3 sequences - (0,5,10) , (100,108,111,115) , (200,201,202)

This logic is really similar to `debounce` operator. But instead of debouncing by real time, I need to debounce by some custom property.

This is how I would do that if timestamp would represent the emission time:

```
List<Model> models = new ArrayList<Model>(10) {{
    add(new Model(0, null));
    add(new Model(5, null));
    add(new Model(10, null));
    add(new Model(100, null));
    add(new Model(108, null));
    add(new Model(111, null));
    add(new Model(115, null));
    add(new Model(200, null));
    add(new Model(201, null));
    add(new Model(202, null));
}};

Observable<Model> modelsObservable = Observable.from(models).share();

modelsObservable.buffer(modelsObservable.debounce(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
        .subscribe(group -> {
            //this is one of my groups
        });
```

It is not necessarily  needs to be a debounce - I was also looking at `groupBy` operator, but I couldn't figure out the proper grouping criteria..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't fiddle with the schedulers, but leverage Buffer/Window (depending if you need downstream observables or collections) and Scan.

In Rx.Net you can achieve it with:

```
        var models = new[] { 0, 5, 10, 100, 108, 111, 115, 200, 201, 202 }
            .ToObservable();

        var enrichedModels = models.Scan(
            new { Current = -1, Prev = -1 },
            (acc, cur) => new { Current = cur, Prev = acc.Current })
            .Skip(1).Publish();

        enrichedModels.Buffer(() => enrichedModels.SkipWhile(em => em.Current < em.Prev + 10))
            .Select(seq => seq.Select(em => em.Prev))
            .Subscribe(seq =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", seq));
            });

        enrichedModels.Connect();
```

Results in:

```
0,5,10
100,108,111,115
200,201
```

Publish/Connect can probably be skipped if your source observable is hot.
rx-java possesses the same operators, but not the anonymous types, I guess they can be replaced either by tuple or a concrete class.

Comment: Interesting. Ill give it a shot. Creating temp collection is the only concern. But not critical

Comment: If you use Window instead of Buffer, there will be no temp collection, syntax is identical

Comment: So I ended up using window as you suggested. Slightly different approach though (due to my specifics), but I got the idea. Looks more native now.

Answer (score 1):

A bit unconventional, but you could use the `TestScheduler` here, schedule the value emission by the data value, then use the debounce-trick with this scheduler and move the virtual time ahead.

```
TestScheduler s = new TestScheduler();
Scheduler.Worker w = s.createWorker();

PublishSubject<Object> subject = PublishSubject.create();

for (Model m : model) {
    w.schedule(() -> subject.onNext(m.data), 
        m.timestamp, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}

subject.buffer(subject.debounce(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, s))
    .subscribe(list -> ...);

s.advanceTimeBy(Long.MAX_VALUE / 2, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

w.unsubscribe();
```

(There were attempts at implementing a Virtual-time scheduler in RxJava but the discussion was abandoned and the proposed implementation rejected.)

Comment: Unconventional, indeed :) It works though, thanks! Just wondering, is it possible to advance time before I subscribe to the stream (or schedule this step somehow)? Im planning to use this observable as part of some bigger transformation observable, so want to isolate `advanceTimeBy` & `w.unsubscribe` from subscription stage. Does it make any sense to create a whole separate operator via `lift` or use `compose`?